# Numerical integration with poles

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, complex, numerical-value, singularity

I have got many errors for this integral. Anyone knows how to fix it? (I am using mathematica12.2)

```
-((E^(-I \[Theta]) z r + 
        E^(I \[Theta]) r zb)/(4 \[Pi] r (-E^(I \[Theta]) r + 
          z) (-E^(-I \[Theta]) r + zb))) /. {z -> \[Rho] Exp[
       I \[Phi]], zb -> \[Rho] Exp[-I \[Phi]]} /. {\[Rho] -> 
    0.5, \[Phi] -> 0.3} // 
 NIntegrate[#, {r, 0, 0.5, \[Infinity]}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], 
    0.3, \[Pi]}, Exclusions -> {{0}, {-Pi, Pi}}] &
```

I think the correct answer should be around 0 to 1

Pole location (r=0.5,theta=0.3) and (r=0,theta from -pi to pi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating analytically it gives complex answer

```
integrand=-((E^(-I *\[Theta]) z*r+E^(I*\[Theta]) r *zb)/(4*\[Pi]*r (-E^(I*\[Theta])*r+z) (-E^(-I*\[Theta])*r+zb)))/. {z->\[Rho] *Exp[I* \[Phi]],zb->\[Rho]* Exp[-I*\[Phi]]}/. {\[Rho]->1/2,\[Phi]->1/3}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Integrate[integrand,{r,0,Infinity},GenerateConditions->False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = Integrate[%, {\[Theta], -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol // N
(*0.470551 - 3.23431 I*)
```

Comment: First integral gives a real valued result, I think(Mathematica v12.2): `Simplify[PowerExpand[
  Integrate[integrand, {r, 0, Infinity}, 
   GenerateConditions -> False]]] (*-(((-1 + 3 \[Pi] + 3 \[Theta]) Cot[1/3 - \[Theta]])/(6 \[Pi]))*)` . That's why I would expect a real result for the second integral  `Log[2 Sin[1/3]]`!